# Setting up server to share music with tv

Tags: ubuntu

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Hopefully first by letting me know if this is possible...

I recently purchased a home theater system which you plug via hdmi into the tv. It has its own nice gui with netflix, and youtube, and blah blah blah. One of the options was to "browse your computer." When you click on it it tries to connect to a server to find music/videos.

Can I use my Ubuntu installed laptop to host a server to put music on and play it wirelessly essentially? I believe this is possible and should be pretty straight forward.

How would I go about creating a server on the same laptop I would be interacting with it...I could then secure copy or sftp the files back and forth. Is there like special settings to keep in mind?

Any words of wisdom would be appreciated. Tx

C

Comment: Yes it is possible, have a look at things like XBMC and mediatomb. The details might depend on what kind of server your TV can recognize. That should be explained in the manual. Let us know what it can deal with and we can suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to confirm which standard your home theater ting is using, but it is probably using DLNA, an overly-cumbersome UPnP-based standard Consumer Electronics Manufacturers use.

I have used 2, [MediaTomb](http://mediatomb.cc/) and [MiniDLNA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/) (now ReadyMedia, recently renamed).  I definitely recommend MiniDLNA.  MediaTomb is overly complicated and doesn't seem to be that actively maintained now.  MiniDLNA just worked once my wife installed it.

Comment: MiniDLNA now up and running in like 10 clicks. Phenomenal thank you.

Comment: @user2008222 Glad it helped.  I like software that just works, and MiniDLNA qualifies.

Comment: I have an external 2TB Western Digital MyBook Live, which runs a Risc processor and Linux, and serves samba shares.  And you can install media software.  This may replace my P3 running MythTv soon.